# Running Stripe Asynchronously

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, stripe-payments

The following code takes few second to run:

`payments = stripe.PaymentIntent.list(limit=10000)`

How I can make the above code run asynchronously?

I tried `await payments = stripe.PaymentIntent.list(limit=10000)` but I received the error `SyntaxError: cannot assign to await expression`

Comment: The syntax is `payments = await stripe.PaymentIntent.list(limit=1000)`.  But that will only work if the function is declared `async`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import time
import asyncio       
import threading


async def myfunction():

    await asyncio.sleep(10) #  sleep for 10 seconds

    payments = stripe.PaymentIntent.list(limit=10000)


server=threading.Thread(target=asyncio.run, args=(myfunction(),))

server.start()
```

Comment: Please include an explanation

Comment: The `stripe.PaymentIntent.list(limit=10000)` function is put inside an asynchronous `myfunction`. And `myfunction` runs in a thread. However, running asynchronous `myfunction` inside a thread gives runtime error. This error is fixed by using `target=asyncio.run` which is available in newer version of python3

Answer (score 3):

I've created a pure async (no threads) stripe client for Python: https://github.com/bhch/async-stripe/. It will give you better performance than threading.

Usage:

```
from async_stripe import stripe

stripe.api_key = '<your stripe api key>'

async myfunction():
    payments = await stripe.PaymentIntent.list(limit=10000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can kick it off without awaiting by calling an async function:

```
async function listPaymentIntents() {
  const payments = await stripe.PaymentIntent.list({limit: 10000});
  console.log('done!');
}

console.log('calling listPaymentIntents!');
listPaymentIntents();
console.log('called listPaymentIntents!');
```

And yes as @Barmar mentions the `await` goes on the value side to handle the promise resolution.

edit: Not an async python expert, but this seems to map to asyncio's concept of [Tasks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#creating-tasks). Perhaps it could be done like so:

```
async def listPaymentIntents():
  payments = stripe.PaymentIntent.list(limit=10000);
  return payments

task = asyncio.create_task(listPaymentIntents())

// await task # optional
```

Comment: I need a code in python. I think the code you provided is Javascript.

Comment: It seems doable with asyncio but I've not used python async much before.